# Algebraically closed field larger than algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Can one provide an example of an algebraically closed field that is larger than algebraic numbers and smaller than real numbers?

Comment: An algebraically closed field cannot be smaller (in the sense of *subsets*) than $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So, what sense of "larger" and "smaller" do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

The algebraic numbers $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ contains the solutions of $X^2+1=0$ so can't be contained in $\mathbb{R}$ as a set. However, if by "smaller" you mean in terms of transcendence degree then you can take the algebraic numbers $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and a transcendental element $T \in \mathbb{R}$. Now take the algebraic closure of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(T)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ (call it $F$). The transcendence degree of $F$ is 1 so its "smaller" than $\mathbb{R}$ (which has uncountable transcendence degree) but bigger than $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ which has transcendence degree 0.

Comment: I'm adraind the OP meant "larger, smaller" in the sense of set inclusion, not transcendence degree nor cardinality (of course).

Comment: I am sorry I sloppily used the terms "smaller" and "larger". What I meant was inclusion.

Comment: @Per Ting: key information like that should be *in the question*, not in a comment to an answer.